# Viewer showing Error when opening the drawing first time

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, forge

I am facing an issue while opening the drawing for the first time in Forge Viewer,
the error message that I get in the console is,
GET http://localhost/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6eXlpYnFqdW8yeW9yNTF2c2d2Y3VzcHlnbnk5amVhbnQtMnRlc3Qvdmx0ZXN0cnZ0LnJ2dA%3D%3D 404 (Not Found)

while the second time and further no such issue is present,

during the second time:

Request URL:
https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6eXlpYnFqdW8yeW9yNTF2c2d2Y3VzcHlnbnk5amVhbnQtMnRlc3Qvdmx0ZXN0cnZ0LnJ2dA%3D%3D?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost

I have noticed that at first it is
http://localhost/derivativeservice

and second time onwards it is
https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/
???

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that when you first try and fetch the model in the first attempt, the requested resource is not found. Hence the 404 error message indicating the resource wasn't found.

In the second attempt, the requested resource seems to be fetched successfully. This could be because the CDN is connecting to the server and getting the resource.